# codeigniter single application multiple databases

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I will be shifting my code base to the new 2.0 framework and just had a few questions on the following points

My urls will be as follows

- example.in/city1
- example.in/city1/admin
- example.in/city2
- example.in/city2/admin

I would like to know what would be the best way to switch the database based on the city in the url? .

In my webroot i will have directories like city1, city2 each containing an index.php file which points to the single code base.

Now i only need a way to switch the database based on the url entered.

Regards,
Sheldon

Comment: why would you whant different databases based on cities ?

Comment: I'd rethink this approach entirely. One database, use a table for each city (or better yet, several tables with appropriate relationships). I can't think of a single reason you'd need to do it like this

Comment: @poelinca, @ross The main reason i was thinking of having multiple databases for the each city is that we have a support center as well as logistics team to cater to customers in each city. So i thought that keeping each citys data in separate databases would make more sense

Comment: bad decision ( atleast from my point of view ), tough it would make sence ( and it would be more fun ) to design such a database structure that allows you to instantly add countries over the cities, worlds over countries, planets over worlds ... you whont need directories but routes, and users, and category trees ( cityes ... ), and acl and resources and ... let you're app be easy extendable with 2 click instead of creating another database and directories and configs ...

Comment: @poelinca My site currently operates in only 1 city and the database has about 150 tables containing information for that city. According to you the better more extendable solution would be better for me to rework all tables structures in database to now have an association with say cityid. So when i switch to another city the data will be filtered out using the city id as the key. –

Comment: @poelinca i do have this hierarchy in place for my current app where i have a city table, then locations associated with that city and the outlets associated with these locations and so on, but since we are in just 1 city the cityid was hard coded all over the site, so now instead i have a list of cities to select from whenever i add a location or an outlet for a particular city. This architecture totally makes sense and is also easily extendable and maintainable.  thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely agree with @poelinca and @Ross, you should definitely consider rethinking your design.

however for reference issues this topic was already covered in the CodeIgniter forums pretty well over [here](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/145901/)

Basically you just configure another set of `$db` items per connection and then request the connection based on those configuration parameters by the CodeIgniter framework, by providing the new `$db` as a parameter for the `DB` class constructor.

Comment: My site currently operates in only 1 city and the database has about 150 tables containing information for that city.

According to you it would be better for me to rework all tables structures in database to now have an association with say cityid.

So when i switch to another city the data will be filtered out using the city id as the key.